# android google map issue with google-play-services_lib

Tags: android, google-maps

I created one android application I followed all the steps to make API keys and intalled google play services from Android SDK Manager. I read so many blogs for integartion google map, I Import the libraty project to my worksapce from "\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib" path. when I tried to add library project from project's property window in android tab I got following out put
[image]
But when I check this library second time than I got following out put in android tab
[image]
I have proble of libraty project. I  used eclipse IDE. I got some solution but for different IDE , so suggest me for best solution..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem usually happens when the path to the library is too long, the solution would be to move the `google-play-services lib` to a place where it path would be shorter and then try to reference it again.

your second problem:

```
"Google Maps Android API(23127): Failed to load map. Could not contact Google servers."
```

caused usually when there is a problem with your API key or a problem with the permissions you have defined in the manifest file, take a look a this post I wrote and go over all the steps to generate the key:

[Google Map API key](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=403)

Next, check steps 5-7 and verify you defined the right permissions:

[Google Map API V2](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes it may happen, you should remove and add the same library again 
        or restart the eclipse and add the library

Comment: thanks sridharcorby for answer, I tried this with  so many time.. also kill process on abd and restarted my System so many times

Comment: is there any other solution?

Comment: @Bhavin Chauhan - check yourProject -- > Android Dependencies -- > you should have 3 Dependencies in it((1)google-play-services.jar.(2)android-support-v4.jar.(3)google-play-services_lib.jar

Comment: patel pratik , thanks for reply i got the solution when I put the project with my project directory and than add library solved my problem.. your listed jar file are there in my project now..

Comment: because I have still another issue.."Google Maps Android API(23127): Failed to load map.  Could not contact Google servers." and my map screen is blanked

Comment: @Bhavin Chauhan- i thought you have not added so i suggested you...anyways we will move further..post your xml here.